# JMeter, how to pass multiple values in one parameter

Tags: jmeter

i have been searching, how can i pass two values in one parameter from a csv file,
for example.  i need to put the names john and mary in the parameter "name"

so the link should look like this ---  http://samplelink.com?name=john&name=mary
BUT some scenario have just one name,, so the link would be --- http://samplelink.com?name=john

Using jmeter for API test

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given you have CSV file which looks like:

   ```
   john,mary
   joe
   ann,jim
   ```
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcesssor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def name = vars.get('name')
   name.split(',').each { currentName-> 
       sampler.addArgument('name', currentName)
   }
   ```
4. That's it, JSR223 PreProcessor will obtain the current value of `${name}` variable, split it by comma and add a request parameter for each found value.

More information: [A Quick Guide to JMeter PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors)

Comment: i responded too late  tho :D:D:D